# How do I limit decimal precision in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I have several floating point values in processing with decimal places beyond 8 digits.

How can I round these values to the tenths before using `text()` to draw them?

Comment: I'm using processing, which is similar to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can format a floating point (`float` or `double`) `x` with 2 decimal places like this:

```
String.format("%.2f", x)
```

This'll give you a `String`.

For example:

```
String.format("%.2f", 12.34567)
```

returns the string `"12.35"`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the nf function described at  http://processing.org/reference/nf_.html . The "right" parameter will allow you to specify the number of decimals to use.

Edit: I realize I misundestood your question; the function I linked to above will truncate, not round. A quick google gave me the following answer:

```
float round(float number, float decimal) {
    return (float)(round((number*pow(10, decimal))))/pow(10, decimal);
}
```

suggested by user Markavian in the thread here: http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1115073288

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use DecimalFormat.

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String output = myFormatter.format(12.34567);
```

[Check this at docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)